# Getting users who installed and uninstalled app on same day with time taken for uninstall in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I have written a query in BigQuery to get users who did app_remove & first_open on the same day, but I am not getting desired output:

```
SELECT
extract(time from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) as Time,
extract(date from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) as Date,
user_pseudo_id,
event_name
FROM
  `mybits-54f8c.analytics_179636122.events_20200917`
WHERE (event_name = "app_remove" or event_name = "first_open")
ORDER BY user_pseudo_id, Date, Time
```

The output table shows this. What I want is entries like 16 and 17 (shown in red), it is the same user who installed and uninstalled the app on same day. I don't want other entries.

I tried 'AND' in place of 'OR', but it didn't work.

Also, the user left in around 1 minute, is it possible to get the difference between the two times?

Any guidance for me will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Shantanu Jain

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT
extract(date from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) as Date,
datedif(min(extract(time from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))),max(extract(time from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))),second) as timediff
user_pseudo_id
FROM
  `mybits-54f8c.analytics_179636122.events_20200917`
WHERE event_name in ("app_remove","first_open")
group by extract(date from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)),user_pseudo_id
having count(distinct event_name)=2
ORDER BY user_pseudo_id, Date
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am getting an error: SELECT list expression references column event_timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:36]

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: @ShantanuJain, I've updated the answer - you can give a try

Comment: Thanks @Fahmi for the quick response. I ran the code, and I got this error: 
"Function not found: datediff; Did you mean date_diff? at [3:1] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.", so I changed the function to 'date_diff', but unfortunately, it gave me another error: "DATE_DIFF does not support the SECOND date part at [3:1] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions." Sorry for bothering again, can you please help with this. Thanks.

Comment: @ShantanuJain, I've updated it - it should datedif instead of datediff - you can check for your reference - https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/DATEDIF-Function_57344707

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user/date pairs, you can use:

```
SELECT extract(date from TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) as Date,
       user_pseudo_id
FROM `mybits-54f8c.analytics_179636122.events_20200917`
WHERE event_name in ('app_remove', 'first_open')
GROUP BY date, user_pseudo_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event_name) = 2;
```

Note:  I am not aware that BigQuery supports `date` for `extract()` -- at least the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract) does not give that as an option.  I would typically just use the `date()` function.

If you want the individual rows -- and your question suggests that is what you do want -- there are a few options, but conceptually, the simplest might be `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM `mybits-54f8c.analytics_179636122.events_20200917` e
WHERE  event_name in ('app_remove', 'first_open') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM `mybits-54f8c.analytics_179636122.events_20200917` e2
              WHERE e2.user_pseudo_id = e.user_pseudo_id AND
                    date(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(e2.event_timestamp)) = date(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(e.event_timestamp)) AND
                    e2.event_name <> e.event_name
             );
```